# How to lock words in error message not to be devided part on line and the rest on new line

Tags: html, angular

I am facing this issue. In Angular 2 we have error message and I don´t know from which reason when there is not enough space for the word it devides this word so that some part stays on the line and the rest is thrown on next line. [Here is the image screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL6Rz.jpg)

Is tere any therm to lock down words?

Thanks.

Comment: This is most likely a CSS issue, try to use `white-space: nowrap;` in your CSS.

Comment: Hi thanks but what I need is just oposit. I guess it should be white-space: wrap; that the word stays locked and not devided. But anyway thanks for hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see the images, but I guess the issue.

use `word-wrap: nowrap` to stop that :

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.one-line {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ultricies.</div>
<div class="one-line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ultricies.</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks also for the hint. I need just wrap function so I will test it out. Thanks.